# Style font awesome icon to the right of input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Having a difficult time forcing this icon to be at the right of the input rather than dropping below. Have changed col number, put in div, etc.. But nothing. Here is how it looks now:

[image]

My code for this is (sample doesn't show closing form tag):

```
    <form class="pptReg" role="form" name="pptReg" novalidate>
        <h1 style="padding-top: 60px; color: #ab2328;">Participant Information</h1>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 naviaInp" style="padding-top: 30px;">
            <label for="empCode">Employer Code</label>
            <input type="text" name="empCode" class="form-control" id="empCode" data-ng-model="pptregistration.coCode" ng-required="true" maxlength="3" autofocus ng-blur="getEmpIdType(true);">
            <a class="questionIcon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle col-md-2 fa-2x" style="float: right;"></i></a>
            <div ng-show="(pptReg.$submitted || pptReg.empCode.$touched) && pptReg.empCode.$error.required">
                <p class="claimError"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i><span>This is a required field.</span></p>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="(pptReg.$submitted || pptReg.empCode.$touched) && empIdType == ''">
                <p class="claimError"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i><span>The Employer Code is invalid.</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It is simply a font awesome icon I am trying to add to the right of the input there. Am using Bootstrap 3 for layout.

Ideas or suggestions (I have come through many in my own head!)?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to restrict the width of the input so that there's enough space next to it for the icon. Then you need to set the input and icon to `display:inline-block;` also, remove the `col-md-2` class from the icon as it is unnecessary. Finally, add `vertical-align:middle;` to the icon so that it's vertically aligned with the input.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="pptReg" role="form" name="pptReg" novalidate="">
    <h1 style="padding-top: 60px; color: #ab2328;">Participant Information</h1>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 naviaInp" style="padding-top: 30px;">
        <label for="empCode">Employer Code</label>
        <input type="text" name="empCode" class="form-control" id="empCode" data-ng-model="pptregistration.coCode" ng-required="true" maxlength="3" autofocus="" ng-blur="getEmpIdType(true);">
        <a class="questionIcon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle col-md-2 fa-2x"></i></a>
        <div ng-show="(pptReg.$submitted || pptReg.empCode.$touched) &amp;&amp; pptReg.empCode.$error.required">
            <p class="claimError"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i><span>This is a required field.</span></p>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="(pptReg.$submitted || pptReg.empCode.$touched) &amp;&amp; empIdType == ''">
            <p class="claimError"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i><span>The Employer Code is invalid.</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.form-control {
  display:inline-block;
  width:90%;
}
a.questionIcon {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

## [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/KcxQiF9K4a)

Answer (score 3):

Add `display: inline;` as follow to question mark:

```
<a class="questionIcon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle col-md-2 fa-2x" style="float: right; display:inline;"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The class **.form-control** makes the empCode input as a block element.  You'll need to add styling to the input to allow for other elements to reside on the same line as it (ie `float:left; display:inline-block;`).

Comment: Good ideas asnd they works, but dang, the responsiveness gets all skewed now. If it ain't one thing, it's another...lol....